# MQ-4 sensitivity characteristics - raw data

Tags: sensor, data, device-characteristics

I need to convert Rs/Ro ratios of my MQ-4 sensor to PPM. For that I found the sensitivity plot in the datasheet (https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-4.pdf). However that is a pdf and an image in it. How can I get the raw values out to get a precise fit function? Is there any standard way of doing that, or do I simply need to use a look&feel approach or fiddle around by counting pixels?

Thanks!

Comment: those plot are made with just a few points, plus the graph is linear, so two points are enough

Comment: According to the data sheet, those curves are typical and vary considerably with changes in temperature and humidity.  The datasheet recommends calibrating the sensor after installation.  The point is that it is probably not worthwhile trying to get a precise reading of the curves.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use MQ sensor characteristic values and had to manually extract it from the image which was cumbersome. Please find the values I extracted in the following report: [mq-4 sensor characteristics](https://datalitique.com/MQ-4-sensor-Rs-to-Ro-ratios-e3da5)